# Kivy - OSError, Still Apps Run Successfully?

Tags: error-handling, kivy

Every time I run a Kivy app I see OSError (see it in last line of my given example). Even though my app runs successfully. What could be the cause of this error?

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
     self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 197, in _thread_run
     _device = Device(_fn)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 131, in __init__
     self._fd = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not important, it just means that kivy checked the possible input providers in your OS and found that this one is forbidden.

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation to give an up vote to your answer. But thanks for the clarification.